# How can I connect to an existing oracle database during installation with Installshield?

Tags: sql, oracle, installation, installshield

I need to connect to an existing `oracle` database during installation, to run sql scripts. I already tried the `SQL` scritps view, but 
when I try connecting through the connection dialog in the wizard, I get

`ERROR:ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`.

I don't even know if this is the right way to connect.
I appreciate if an expert in Install Shield 2019 could explain the proper way to connect to an existing database.

Comment: Does your `tnsnames.ora` list the database you are attempting to connect to?  Have you tried the `tnsping` command? Does the installshield install process run under a Windows user that has access to the Oracle database?

Comment: The answer for all questions is yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out calling SQLPlus console with argument the script I want to run.
This is possible through Custom action

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to connect with Oracle database using Installshield many years ago. But, we had designed custom screen for capturing the Database details(local or remote, port, username, password).
For validating the above database details, custom action was written on the event of Next button. The Custom action called the installscript function which eventually calls a java program using LaunchAppandWait function.
You may write your own custom action in any desired language and can pass the required Oracle database string.